# how to remove the duplicate xml notes content using jquery

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I am trying to remove the duplicate xml notes using jquery, can any one help?

**My xml:**

```
<Accounts>
  <Account>
    <Company>Company 1</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Company>Company 1</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Company>Company 1</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
</Accounts>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var LatestAccounturl = "scripts/jqwidgets/sampledata/latestAccountUpdates.xml";

var LatestAccountsource =
{
    datatype: "xml",
    mtype: 'GET',
    datafields: [
        { name: 'Company', type: 'String'},
        { name: 'AccountNo', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'CCY', type: 'String' },
        { name: 'Link', type: 'bool' },
        { name: 'StatusIMG', type: 'String' }
    ],      
    root: "Accounts",
    record: "Account",
    url: LatestAccounturl       
};


var xml = $(xml);
$('Accounts > Company', xml).each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});

});
```

I want to check if the `<company>` node having the same value (duplicated) then i need to remove the duplicated item,  for this first step I am trying to get the xml node text value, which is not  working in my alert:( any solution or better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the select: `Accounts > Company` tries to select **direct** children, but in the xml, Company is not a direct child of `Accounts`.

correct would be

```
$('Accounts Company', xml).each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

without the `>`, or

```
$('Accounts > Account', xml).each(function() {
    alert($(this).find("Company").text());
});
```

which would be the preffered method, since `this` will hold the full account....now you can check for the company already existing and use `$(this).remove()` to delete the node, in case its already present.

Comment: Still iam not getting the alert, u have any idea? why its not getting in alert? iam calling in ready after the ajax call...

Comment: well, what happens between the declaration of `LatestAccountsource` and `var xml = $(xml);`? maybe your xml is just empty?

Comment: you left out the part where you actually request the data from the server...maybe the problem is there?

Comment: I have data in my xml as like my above construct. how to check if the path is right ? because in the grid(using jqxgrid) the data is loading right now.. but when i try to get the get value using jquery its not working!!got it ? also i just running in my local not from server...

Comment: okay, then your problem is `var xml = $(xml);` which simply does nothing...guess what you actually wanted to do is `var xml = $('#xml');` or `var xml = $('xml');` (depending on your DOM)

Comment: I tryed both the way as u suggested for var xml declaration still the alert is not firing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66578/discussion-between-mr-manhattan-and-krish).